# Create hash by ignoring null in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create hash of ('a', 'b', 'c', null) by ignoring null. I used below statement to do the same but it returns null.

I want (select SHA2_HEX(a|b|c) whereas Below statement does (select SHA2_HEX(null)

```
(select SHA2_HEX(CONCAT_WS('|', 'a', 'b', 'c', null)))
```

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT_WS will produce NULL as soon as one of the values is NULL. Try to add coalesce(your_column, ''), then at least the final output of CONCAT_WS is not NULL. But: Result is still not correct, because you will have |a|b|c| (note the last |).

```
select SHA2_HEX(CONCAT_WS('|', 'a', 'b', 'c', coalesce(null, '')))
```

Otherwise just do `CONCAT('|', 'a', '|', 'b', '|', 'c', coalesce(null, ''))`

Answer (score 0):

[ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact.html) drops NULL's and then [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html) gives the string you are looking for:

```
select 
    CONCAT_WS('|', 'a', 'b', 'c', null) as d1
    ,array_construct('a', 'b', 'c', null) as a1
    ,ARRAY_TO_STRING(a1, '|') as d2
    ,array_construct_compact('a', 'b', 'c', null) as a2
    ,ARRAY_TO_STRING(a2, '|') as d3
    ;
```

| D1 | A1 | D2 | A2 | D3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | [ "a", "b", "c", undefined ] | a|b|c| | [ "a", "b", "c" ] | a|b|c |

thus

```
select SHA2_HEX(ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_construct_compact('a', 'b', 'c', null),'|'));
```

gives:

| SHA2_HEX(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT('A', 'B', 'C', NULL),'|')) |
| --- |
| a52dd81bfd5e4e66d96b9f598382f6cbf8c5c3897654e6ae9055e03620fcf38e |